# calling servlet using POST from java program

Tags: servlets

This question is asked many times but somehow i'm unable to get my program working.

Here is my java program:

```
public static void main( String [] args ) {

    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/servletname");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        BufferedWriter out = 
            new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( conn.getOutputStream() ) );
        //out.write("xml=" + param1 + "\r\n");
        out.write("xml=xmltest\r\n");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        BufferedReader in = 
            new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( conn.getInputStream() ) );

        String response;
        while ( (response = in.readLine()) != null ) {
            System.out.println( response );
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch ( MalformedURLException ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        // a real program would need to handle this exception
    }
    catch ( IOException ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        // a real program would need to handle this exception
    }
}
```

It throws exception while calling conn.getInputStream()

Exception throws is here:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/webapp/servletname  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
at com.barcap.mdm.nh.cron.TestUpload.main(TestUpload.java:35)
```

My servlet code is here:

```
public class servletname extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public servletname() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("GET method reached .... but it's not supported");
    throw new ServletException("'GET' method not supported. 'POST' method required.");
    //doPost(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("POST method reached");

    response.setContentType("text/xml");
    List<UploadUserVO> list = null;
    String xml = request.getParameter("xml");
    String responseXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><response result=\"__responseString__\"></response>";

    System.out.println("XML : " + xml);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {
                  // perform some task here 
               } catch (Exception e)
}}}}
```

Can somebody pointout what's missing or what's wrong that i'm doing?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace including the root cause. The answer is in there.

Comment: That's the full stack trace. There is no other information .... that's why i'm also unable to debug further.

Comment: You need to read the server log (there where the servlet runs), not the client log (there where your `main()` prints to). Otherwise, read `URLConnection#getErrorStream()` which should return a HTML flavored error page with the stack trace (although this may not contain the *complete* stacktrace).

Comment: Can you please let me know which exact log i need to look into .... in the tomcat log directory, i didn't find any info ... there are catalina,localhost and manager logs. No info in them.                                                                Also, my client and server are in the same project ... i'm developing API for some purose which suppose to use only POST method. I want to test the API beforehand to make sure everything is just fine. I wrote a simple HTML program and called the servlet using POST method using AJAX. It works fine. But somehow my java client ..unable make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was not working because i had a filter for the web request which expects credentials to pass through. In the browser, it was ok however java client didn't had that info ... that's why it didn't work. After commenting the filter in web.xml it works.  Otherwise, i can hardcode the credentials in request in java client, it works fine too.